# CSS file not getting linked

Tags: html, css

So i have a basic html file and css file in different folders. The main folder "code" has two folders: "templates" and "css".

home.html is in the "templates" folder and main.css is in the "css" folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
```

I used this link and it works fine locally but when i connected to a localhost port, the css file is not being read at all. Any idea why?

I should probably also add that I'm using google app engine and deploying the website throught that. This is the short python code:

```
import bottle
from bottle import route
from string import Template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
bottle.app().catchall=False

@route('/')
def readpage():
    fid = open('templates/home.html')
    return fid

util.run_wsgi_app(bottle.default_app())
```

And the app.yaml handlers:

```
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.py

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /media
  static_dir: media
```

FIXED: had to add this instead to the yaml file:

```
- url: /css/main.css
  static_files: css/main.css
  upload: css/main.css
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Help us out by posting how your HTML is linking to your CSS file and any web server configuration related to that site.

Comment: Fixed, I did not space the code properly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that HTML. Double-check that the CSS is on the server, an accessible, for example by entering its URL into the address bar. Do you already know the Firefox web console? It will tell you why a file was not loaded (from the client's perspective).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to use absolute paths. If the root of the virtual-host or whatnot is the one containing both `templates` and `css`, then you should use just `/css/main.css`.

This will solve the issue while looking at `http://localhost/templates/home.html`, but probably won't work on some WYSIWYG editors or while accessing the file outside of the web server. Try to find out which development environment works better for you, so that you avoid these problems.